# How can I filter an array on multiple criteria?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I'm trying to find all array elements starting with S and N, but the below code doesn't do it:

```
@a = qw(sonata Samsung sony icic huawie nissan nokia);
```

here is my code

```
@filter = grep { (/^s (.*)$/ig) && (/^n(.*)$/ig) } @a;
print "@filter \n";
```

Comment: i have used @a=qw(sonata Samsung sony icic huawie nissan nokia);
@filter=grep{/^s(.*)$/ig}@a;
print "@filter \n";
@filters=grep{/^n(.*)$/ig}@a;
print "@filters \n";
@final=(@filter,@filters);
print "@final \n";

Comment: You should [edit] your question to add this kind of info, not comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you've introduced whitespace into your regexes. You are also asking for cases where the string begins with the character 'S' or the character 'N', so your logic is an OR statement, rather than an AND statement as written. If all you care about is the first character, that's all you need in your pattern, and you want to use a logical OR.

```
@a = qw(sonata Samsung sony icic huawie nissan nokia);
@filter = grep { /^s/i || /^n/i } @a;
print "@filter \n";
```

Result:

```
sonata Samsung sony nissan nokia
```

Edit -- or more succinctly with a character class

```
@a = qw(sonata Samsung sony icic huawie nissan nokia);
@filter = grep { /^[sn]/i } @a;
print "@filter \n";
```

Comment: Thanks so much @MikeCovington!

Comment: The downvotes was for failing to answer the actual question.  I don't think that an answer that doesn't address the `&&` issue is useful.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but the logic the OP was asking for was to match S OR N, rather than S AND N (even though it was originally written S and N -- the OP meant S or N)

Comment: It would (IMO) greatly improve your answer if you actually said that, as this is the root of the problem the OP is having. The whitespacing is really a secondary issue when the core problem of 'starts with S and N' will never match, because it can't.

Comment: @Sobrique, I've added that explanation. Good idea.

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is one of logic.  You say you want to filter for all strings that "start with S and N", but that's not true.  You want all strings that start with *one of* S or N.

For a string to "start with S and N", its first character would have to be S and it would *also* have to be N, which is not possible.

The expression

```
grep { (/^s (.*)$/ig) and (/^n(.*)$/ig) } @a;
```

will always return the empty list, no matter what the value of `@a` happens to be.  Each element in `@a` will be considered, but none of them start with both `s` and `n` -- because that is impossible.

What you want instead is a test whether strings in `@a` match *either* S *or* N, like so:

```
grep { (/^s (.*)$/ig) or (/^n(.*)$/ig) } @a;
```

Wanting to match a number of possibilities is actually a pretty common need, though, so there's a special notation for doing so.  A ["character class"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html) creates a new atom that matches any one of several possibilities.  `.` is a character class, and custom character classes can be created with angle brackets, `[]`.

Thus:

```
grep { /^[sn]/i) } @a;
```

Comment: `g` modifier on pattern is probably redundant here too.

Comment: @sobrique True! Fixing.

Answer (score 0):

Just match anything word which is start with `s` or `n`. Following code will give you desire output:

```
my @arr = qw(sonata Samsung sony icic huawie nissan nokia);
my @filter = grep { /^[sn]/i } @arr;
print "@filter \n";
```

Where `^[sn]` will match any of word beginning with `s` or `n`.

Output:

```
sonata Samsung sony nissan nokia
```